# Use of "business" for non-profit organizations

Tags: resume, job-search, cover-letter

I am writing my cover letter and wanted to check whether this phrasing is also appropriate if our clients include non-profit organizations:

> It will enable me to reach my full potential and collaborate with
>   various clients in multiple industries to change and shape the future
>   of their business.

Comment: Hello robotlover and welcome to this site.Who are your clients? Are they previous clients of yours, or are they clients of your potential employer's? Generally if either of those lists contain businesses, you're fine.

Comment: I don't know who the clients are and this cover letter is for strategic consulting positions

Comment: `"It will enable me to reach my full potential and collaborate with various clients in multiple industries to change and shape the future of their business."` - If you're looking for editorial opinions, that statement sounds like bootlicking corporate speak nonsense. I doubt anyone reading that would think "We have to hire this person!" Maybe do a Google search for what to include in your cover letter to come up with one that will work better for you.

Comment: please don't answer in comments

Comment: This is for management consulting.

Answer (score 3):

It'd mostly be OK, but if you want to nitpick, change "business" to "endeavors".

Comment: do you have experience reading this type of copy? what do you pay attention to as a reader?

Answer (score 0):

Not-for-profit orgs' operations generally include "program" -- the stuff they do -- and "development" -- fundraising, grant-writing, etc.

You should write a separate cover letter for each application you submit. The cover letter should show  some knowledge of each company or organization's work.  Its purpose is to explain how you are the very best choice for the specific position they are offering.

Job postings for not-for-profit orgs usually mention whether the opening is in development or program. Make your cover letter responsive to the posting.

So, with respect, it's a bad idea to try to craft "one size fits all" wording for a cover letter.

Comment: I don't blame you - I thought exactly same as the last line in your answer, but it seems that's not the case. :)

Comment: This is for a strategy consulting job. So our clients include both large corporates and non profit